# Actionscript-3/Socket: more than 100 ms between ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA events?

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, sockets, tcp

I'm sending images from a server, in C-berkeley sockets, to a Flash client, both on the same Linux machine:

- Average size of each package: 35000 bytes.
- Flash requests an image, and the server sends it.
- Server spends 30 ms to get,compress and send the image.
- OpenCV is used to grab each frame from a webcam.
- On Flash, the elapsed time between two reception events (ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA is 170 ms. So it displays images with a low frame rate.
- The visualization is not smooth but blurred.

Anyway, the server never waits more than 40 ms to get a client's request, this is what I measure at least..., so is either Flash or server "lying" to me?

If I connect the same Flash to a "as3-server" (OpenKinect server which gets images from the Microsoft's Kinect), everything is OK.

Maybe there is some issue on the server side but I'm using a dedicated one with the classical functions (bind, accept, read, write and close).

Regards.

Comment: Solved. OpenCV takes 90 ms in order to grab a frame (at least from my cheap webcam). That was delaying everything.